# Não consigo usar os pacotes do PIP

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, packages, pip

Sou novo no python e com gerenciamento de pacotes, então várias dúvidas acabam surgindo, gostaria que alguém pudesse me ajudar a esclarecer.

Quando eu instalo um pacote via pip, ex: `pip install opencv-python`, eu simplesmente abro o CMD em admin e executo o comando.

Quando eu crio o projeto e importo a biblioteca, nesse caso `import cv2`, os compiladores não reconhecem; somente se eu der o `pip` dentro da pasta do projeto.

Gostaria de saber se realmente é para ser assim, ou a instalação deve ser de forma "global"?

O que eu estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Anaconda

Se você possui o IDE da anaconda e o sistema operacional Windows, você simplesmente pode executar esse seguinte código:

```py
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv
```

#### Linux

Se você possui o sistema operacional Linux, você pode simplesmente fazer dessa maneira

```py
pip install opencv-python
```

ou

```py
conda install opencv
```

ou

```py
sudo pip3 install opencv-python
```

#### Windows sem a IDE anaconda

Se você possui apenas o Windows e o Python, você pode utilizar esses seguintes comandos no terminal do CMD (obs: não pode ser no terminal do Python):

```py
pip3 install opencv-python
```

ou

```
pip install opencv-python
```

#### Teste

Para certificar se você conseguiu instalar a biblioteca com sucesso, basta você abrir o terminal do Python e importar o módulo cv2. Caso o terminal não informe nenhum erro, deu certo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### PyCharm

Se utiliza o PyCharm como IDE e importou o módulo cv2 (já instalado) e não funcionou, você tem que fazer algumas configurações na IDE para funcionar. Da uma olhada nesse site para saber como que configura a IDE para reconhecer o cv2 [PyCharm não reconhece cv2](https://www.ti-enxame.com/pt/python/o-pycharm-nao-reconhece-o-cv2-como-um-modulo/823200888/)

Comment: Também deve falar sobre ambientes virtuais. https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/venv.html e https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Answer (score 0):

Você pode estar passando por esses 2 problemas.
1 - A "chamada" do pacote pode estar errada, você pode ter que especificar onde está o cv2 com um "from opencv-python < (Isso daqui pode variar) import cv2".
2 - Se você estiver usando PyCharm para desenvolver o compilador que o seu PyCharm está usando é o virtual, ai ele pode não pegar o pacote que você baixou na sua maquina. Em configurações do Pycharm e até mesmo nas configurações de execução do programa você pode editar o compilador que está utilizando, se o PyCharm estiver usando o compilador virtual só aponta ele para o compilador da maquina passando o caminho de instalação do Python.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).